# Powershell loop deal with multiple AD users in output

Tags: loops, powershell, active-directory

I have constructed below to show an certain active directory users details and all their groups.

This works ok if only one user is returned howver if multiple users are returned I get an error with this section: `"Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountname | select name"`

I've looked in the direction of for loops but haven't yet found a solution

I need each user found displayed with their groups.
I plan to use this script to quickly gather info to troubleshoot user issues.

Thanks for reading

```
add-pssnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement

import-module activedirectory

clear-host

$name = read-host 'Whats the name ?'

$user = Get-qAduser $name -properties *

$user | select name,SamAccountName,AccountIsLockedOut,PasswordStatus,PasswordLastSet,PasswordExpires,email,ParentContainerDN,CreationDate | format-list

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountname | select name

cmd /c pause | Out-Null
```

Comment: Basically `$user | ForEach-Object { <do some stuff here> }`. To refer to the current element of the `$user` collection inside the loop use `$_` object. One more thing: `-properties *` will pull lots of stuff from the domain controller. For faster performance specify only the properties you're really going to use.

Comment: Can you post the error you get? It's difficult to be sure that a foreach is the correct solution without the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assume you're getting a list back and then use a `foreach` to iterate over the list:

```
add-pssnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement    
import-module activedirectory

clear-host

$name = read-host 'Whats the name ?'    
$users = Get-qAduser $name -properties *

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user | select name,SamAccountName,AccountIsLockedOut,PasswordStatus,PasswordLastSet,PasswordExpires,email,ParentContainerDN,CreationDate | format-list

    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountname | select name
}
```

Comment: That works thanks, Only thing is...    The group output is at the bottom and not underneath each user account so we just see a list of groups at end but don't know which group matches which account.  
name

Comment: @Confuseis I've updated my answer to reflect your comment

Comment: Thats Great.   The format-list was causing an error so I removed that.  The output was blended together so I added a write-host "--------"  to put a line in  to separate the output.  Now its a very quick way to get user info.   Appreciate your help, Thanks